# как удалить PHP_EOL . из строки

Tags: php, строки

в файл записывается текст вот так , по этому примеру не выходит

```
//Файлы
$admfile = 'admin.php';
$admexphrase = "PHP_EOL" . '<p><a href="admintoursample.php">toursample.php</a></p>';

if(file_put_contents($admfile, PHP_EOL . $admexphrase, FILE_APPEND)) {
    echo "succesadm";
}

//Удаляется вот так 
$admcont = file_get_contents($admfile);
$admcontold = array("$admexphrase");
$admcontnew = array("");
$admphrase  = str_replace($admcontold, $admcontnew, $admcont);
if(file_put_contents($admfile, $admphrase)) {
    echo "succes page\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

решил вопрос , кому понадобится вот код

new.php //создает файл с текстом

```
$file = "text.php";
$text = "testvalue";
$sometext = PHP_EOL . $text;
if((file_put_contents($file, $sometext)) == TRUE) {
echo "ok2";
echo $sometext;
}
```

del.php //удаляет файл и PHP_EOL

```
$file = "text.php";
$filecont = file_get_contents($file); //работает
$oldtext ="testvalue";
$old = PHP_EOL . $oldtext;
$new = "";


$contold = array($old);
$contnew = array($new);
$newphrase = str_replace($contold, $contnew, $filecont);
if(file_put_contents($file, $newphrase)) echo 'ok';
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно конечно и так, а можно и просто функцией trim

```
trim($sometext);
```